# DB2 on Cloud: Table not found error when uploading CSV files

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud

When uploading csv files into IBM DB2 on Cloud Lite Platform, I got the following messages:

> "HWCADM0029E: O descarte de "YPJ62009"."CHICAGO_CRIME_DATA" falhou.
> "YPJ62009.CHICAGO_CRIME_DATA" is an undefined name "
>
> "HWCADM0002E: A Tabela YPJ62009CENSUS_DATA não pode ser localizada."
> (Table YPJ62009CENSUS_DATA not found)
>
> "HWCADM0002E: A Tabela YPJ62009CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS não pode ser
> localizada."(Table YPJ62009CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS not found)
>
> "HWCADM0002E: A Tabela YPJ62009CENSUSDATA não pode ser localizada."
> (Table YPJ62009CENSUSDATA not found)

I´ve been trying to upload some csv files into  my IBM DB2 on Cloud account, to no avail. And since my plan is Lite, I am provided no support from IBM team to solve this problem. I got stuck because there is an IBM course on Coursera about using Python+IBM DB2, and i can´t finish the course, as I am not even able to upload successfully files. May somene enlighten me in this subject?

My SCHEMA´s name is YPJ62009.

Comment: What's the result of the following query? `SELECT TABNAME FROM SYSCAT.TABLES WHERE TABSCHEMA = 'YPJ62009' AND UPPER (TABNAME) = 'CHICAGO_CRIME_DATA'`

Comment: Identifiers for tables have two parts, a schema and the object name, separated by a dot (.). Based on the errors it seems that there is some misconfiguration. Why does the error say table "YPJ62009CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS"?

Comment: I wrote the query "SELECT TABNAME FROM SYSCAT.TABLES WHERE TABSCHEMA = 'YPJ62009' AND UPPER (TABNAME) = 'CENSUSDATA' " and also "SELECT TABNAME FROM SYSCAT.TABLES WHERE TABSCHEMA = 'YPJ62009' AND UPPER (TABNAME) = 'CRIMEDATA' " and the ressult was "CENSUSDATA" and "CRIMEDATA" respectively.

Comment: I´ve erased the DB2 from IBM Cloud and I´m waiting to finish re-raising it again.